# chmod for all folders created by specific user

Tags: bash, chmod

Say I have the following folder structure

```
folder/
├─ subfodler_2/     #User1
├─ subfolder_3/     #User2
├─ subfolder_1/     #User1
```

where I want to `chmod` all the folders (and files) created by `User1` to, say, 777.

I know I cant get the files by

```bsh
ls -la | grep User1
```

and I know how to `chmod` a specific folder, but I don't know how to "use the output" of `ls` i.e parse it to `chmod` afterwards.

It does not have to be a one-liner if I can write it as a bash-script it would be fine aswell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` to search for specific files.  `-user User1` will filter results to only those owned by User1.

Then you can use `-exec` to run a command on those files

```
find folder -user User1 -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

If none of your files are executable already (maybe you're doing this on a library of PDFs), then 777 may not be the cleanest solution.  In that case you could do this to make directories world-readable/writable/executable, but files only world-readable/writable.

```
find folder -user User1 -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
find folder -user User1 -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +
```

---

Your original question asked about parsing `ls`.  You shouldn't do that.  Further reading on that matter:

[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: Just found out that adding `-maxdepth 1` returns only the folders. THanks a lot

Comment: `-type f` will find regular files. that still leaves out all the other stuff, like device nodes, named sockets, pipes and symlinks. Not that it matters here, you can't change the permissions of a symlink itself, and you probably don't have those others.